# A long query optimization

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-optimization

I have a form that contains many records ,If I click on a record another form should be appear with detail of that previous record.In the second form I have many Textfield that fill from these Long query:

```
  SELECT tb_bauteile.*, tb_bauteile.CDT AS CdtNr, tb_Fahrzeug.ID, tb_Pinnummern.Pin,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS KS_Plus,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.CDT from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS CDT_Plus, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS Pfad_Plus, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerunterpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS UPfad_Plus,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Minus] ) AS KS_Minus, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.CDT from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Minus] ) AS CDT_Minus,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Minus] ) AS Pfad_Minus,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerunterpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Minus] ) AS UPfad_Minus,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Unterbrechung] ) AS Unterbr,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.CDT from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Unterbrechung] ) AS CDT_Unterbr,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Unterbrechung] ) AS Pfad_Unterbr, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerunterpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Unterbrechung] ) AS UPfad_Unterbr, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Aderschl] ) AS Aderschl, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.CDT from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Aderschl] ) AS CDT_Aderschl, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Aderschl] ) AS Pfad_Aderschl, 

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerunterpfad from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Aderschl] ) AS UPfad_Aderschl,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.F_Klasse_EU from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS CLA_EU,

    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.F_Klasse_US from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS CLA_US

    FROM (tb_Pinnummern INNER JOIN tb_Fahrzeug ON tb_Pinnummern.SG = tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG) INNER JOIN tb_bauteile ON tb_Pinnummern.Bauteil = tb_bauteile.ID
    WHERE (((tb_Fahrzeug.ID)=[forms]![frm_fahrzeug]![id]));
```

and this form is very  slow and I want to make it better,i put Index on necessary field ,It made the time less than before but slow

I tought that I can put each query on each textfield(in controlelementcontent)  i.e:

```
SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus]
```

but that does not work and show me no data.What dou you mean? Is it possible to do that? where did I make a mistake?

Thank you very much for your answers

Babak

Comment: I can imagine that that query is slow. Where is this query called (is it in an event, on click, on load etc?). I think you could optimize this by moving the SELECTs that are "inside" the first SELECT. Execute the SELECTs that are inside separately as queries of their own. Try putting the different columns that are SELECTed from the same table with the same WHERE criteria into the same SELECT statements.

Comment: Onclick event,but the aliases?they used  in the form on textfield to show data

Answer (score 3):

You can improve the original query by rewriting it as 7 joins, instead of 3 joins and 18 sub-queries, as follows:

```
SELECT bau.*, bau.CDT AS CdtNr, fze.ID, tpi.Pin
, fpl.F_Klasse_EU AS CLA_EU , fpl.F_Klasse_US AS CLA_US
, fpl.OBD_Code AS KS_Plus, fpl.CDT AS CDT_Plus
, fpl.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Plus, fpl.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Plus
, fmi.OBD_Code AS KS_Minus, fmi.CDT AS CDT_Minus
, fmi.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Minus, fmi.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Minus
, fub.OBD_Code AS Unterbr, fub.CDT AS CDT_Unterbr
, fub.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Unterbr, fub.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Unterbr
, fad.OBD_Code AS Aderschl, fad.CDT AS CDT_Aderschl
, fad.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Aderschl, fad.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Aderschl
FROM tb_Fahrzeug                AS fze
JOIN tb_Pinnummern              AS tpi ON tpi.SG = fze.Motor_SG
JOIN tb_bauteile                AS bau ON bau.ID = tpi.Bauteil
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fpl ON fpl.ID = bau.[FC_Plus]
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fmi ON fmi.ID = bau.[FC_Minus]
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fub ON fub.ID = bau.[FC_Unterbrechung]
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fad ON fad.ID = bau.[FC_Aderschl]
WHERE fze.ID = [forms]![frm_fahrzeug]![id];
```

For index matters concerning to this query only, you can create clustered indexes over ID columns and and regular indexes for tb_bauteile.SG (assuming MSSQL syntax and no other clustered indexes ):

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx0 ON tb_Fahrzeug (id);
CREATE INDEX idx0 ON tb_Pinnummern (SG);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx0 ON tb_bauteile (ID);
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx0 ON Fehlercodes_akt_Liste (ID);
```

As a last consideration, consider not using the asterisk selector (from original `tb_bauteile.*`) for documentation and IO purposes. Please remember that RDBMS performance issues depend heavily on the actual environment setup.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer,I use MS access 2003 ,I wanted to try this query but it said me PROBLEM in FROM section :(

Comment: I tested a variation of this query in sql-fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0db08/2] and it worked right. I'm not an Access expert, but maybe it needs the `AS` separator between the table and the alias into the `FROM` clause (added to the script).

Comment: Thank you Lima , instead of JOIN ,INNER JOIN should be used in ACCESS and Access needs brackets to i.e `SELECT  *
FROM    ((((((tb_Fahrzeug AS fze
        JOIN tb_Pinnummern AS tpi ON tpi.SG = fze.Motor_SG)
        JOIN tb_bauteile AS bau ON bau.ID = tpi.Bauteil)
LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fpl ON fpl.ID = bau.[FC_Plus])LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fmi ON fmi.ID = bau.[FC_Minus])LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fub ON fub.ID = bau.[FC_Unterbrechung])LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS fad ON fad.ID = bau.[FC_Aderschl])
WHERE   fze.ID = '[forms]![frm_fahrzeug]![id]'; 
`

Comment: but another thing ,your query doesnt work as the same with the first query . It needs tbbauteileID

Answer (score 2):

Please change the sub queries to `LEFT JOIN`s. Like this:

```
SELECT tb_bauteile.*, tb_bauteile.CDT AS CdtNr, tb_Fahrzeug.ID, tb_Pinnummern.Pin,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.OBD_Code AS KS_Plus,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.CDT AS CDT_Plus, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Plus, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Plus,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Minus.OBD_Code AS KS_Minus, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Minus.CDT AS CDT_Minus,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Minus.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Minus,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Minus.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Minus,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Unterbrechung.OBD_Code AS Unterbr,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Unterbrechung.CDT AS CDT_Unterbr,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Unterbrechung.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Unterbr, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Unterbrechung.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Unterbr, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Aderschl.OBD_Code AS Aderschl, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Aderschl.CDT AS CDT_Aderschl, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Aderschl.Fehlerpfad AS Pfad_Aderschl, 
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Aderschl.Fehlerunterpfad AS UPfad_Aderschl,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.F_Klasse_EU AS CLA_EU,
    Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.F_Klasse_US AS CLA_US
    FROM tb_Pinnummern 
    INNER JOIN tb_Fahrzeug 
        ON tb_Pinnummern.SG = tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG
    INNER JOIN tb_bauteile 
        ON tb_Pinnummern.Bauteil = tb_bauteile.ID
    LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus
        ON Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.ID=tb_bauteile.[FC_Plus]

    LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Minus
        ON Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Minus.ID=tb_bauteile.[FC_Minus]

    LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Unterbrechung
        ON Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Unterbrechung.ID=tb_bauteile.[FC_Unterbrechung]

    LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Aderschl
        ON Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Aderschl.ID=tb_bauteile.[FC_Aderschl]


    WHERE (((tb_Fahrzeug.ID)=[forms]![frm_fahrzeug]![id]));
```

I don't know where all the columns are coming from. But this suggestion if you get it to work will perform faster then all your really strange sub queries. I can see a potential problem with doing sub queries like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste 
     Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Aderschl] ) AS Aderschl, 
.....
```

What happends if one of them return more the one value? You will probably get an exception saying that a the sub query can not return more the one value. So if you are planing in the future to do sub queries like that. At least put a `TOP 1` on them. Like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste 
     Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Aderschl] ) AS Aderschl, 
    .....
```

But I will still not recommend that as a solution. Because it is not a optimize way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer .these queries return only one resualt ut the compiler said me that I have a syntax problem in this section:` tb_Pinnummern.SG = tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG INNER JOIN tb_bauteile ON tb_Pinnummern.Bauteil = tb_bauteile.ID LEFT JOIN Fehlercodes_akt_Liste AS Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus ON Fehlercodes_akt_Liste_FC_Plus.ID=tb_bauteile.[FC_Plus]`

Comment: Thanks I tested your answer .It worked but both of them( the query with sub select and your query with joins) need the same time 10 seconds to run

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to add the table Fehlercodes_akt_Liste  on your from clause.

Your'e  gonna have to add it 4 times but I believe its better than running 18 selects on it per row of the current query

Comment: would you please explain me in detail if possible?

Comment: well, instead of  (SELECT Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.OBD_Code from Fehlercodes_akt_Liste Where Fehlercodes_akt_Liste.ID=[FC_Plus] ) AS KS_Plus (for example), you add the Fehlercodes_akt_Liste to your main join (on the from clause)

Comment: in this situation I have no alias for queries(i.e KS_Plus) but I want to have them ,I need them on my form.Sorry sorry sorry It is not clear form me :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the FC_PLUS, FC_MINUS, FC_Unterbrechung etc. in your tables (bauteile, Fahrzeug,Pinnummer. So if those are just Values you give to the subform you dont have to use them in the Datasource. Just use that one SELECT statement in whatever Field you need the data.

Comment: these fields come from  tb_bauteile.*